# Cannot find file source when processing file with execAndWait interceptor of struts-jquery

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

Using `struts-jquery`, I've created a page that allow an user to upload an excel file, and have the contents displayed without refreshing the page.

When I try to use `execAndWait` interceptor to display a wait page as a remote page, I receive an exception telling me it can't find source of the file.

Can someone provide an answer?

**Update**
I got null pointer exception for the uploaded file object

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)

when I tried to pass a file object (from the jsp page) as an argument on the following line

```
Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
```

This is my action in the struts.xml

```
<action name="readExcel" class="th.co.gosoft.gosd.action.ImportDataAction" method="readExcel">
        <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
            <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="wait">/jsp/goSD/wait.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/goSD/SearchTable/importPreview.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

But when I remove the

> interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"

Everything is fine.

Comment: A post of the exact error message would definitely help.

Comment: Show your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using ONLY `execAndWait` interceptor for your action. You need to define `defaultStack` also.

```
<action name="readExcel" class="th.co.gosoft.gosd.action.ImportDataAction" method="readExcel">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
            <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="wait">/jsp/goSD/wait.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/goSD/SearchTable/importPreview.jsp</result>
</action>
```